# How to configure new Doctrine 3.0

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have an error with Doctrine 3.0:

```php
In ArrayNode.php line 320:
                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  Unrecognized option "migrations_paths" under "doctrine_migrations". Available options are "all_or_nothing", "column_length", "column_name", "custom_template", "dir_name", "executed_at_colum  
  n_name", "name", "namespace", "organize_migrations", "table_name".
```

I checked the upgrade on GitHub but still not working

My actual doctrine_migrations.yaml*

```yaml
doctrine_migrations:
    migrations_paths:
        # namespace is arbitrary but should be different from App\Migrations
        # as migrations classes should NOT be autoloaded
        'DoctrineMigrations': '%kernel.project_dir%/migrations'
```

Thanks for your hels

Comment: your error message *actually* sounds like you still have doctrine/migrations 2.x installed and not version 3.x, hence your upgraded config is for the wrong version. I also wouldn't force it as this point, to be honest and keep it at 2.x

Comment: Ok i came back  2.2.1 and change the doctrine_migrations.yaml it's ok thank you
if I do a composer install or update it will bring me back to 3.0 ?

Comment: you can update your composer.json so that doctrine/migrations has version "^2.2", which will prevent 3.0 from being installed

Answer (score 1):

If you have doctrine migrations ^2.0 and updated to ^3.0 correct config will be:

```yaml
doctrine_migrations:
    migrations_paths:
        'DoctrineMigrations': '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Migrations'
    storage:
        table_storage:
            table_name: 'migration_versions'
            version_column_name: 'version'
            version_column_length: 255
            executed_at_column_name: 'executed_at'
            execution_time_column_name: 'execution_time'
```

Change config and then run command to sync metadata:

```sh
 bin/console doctrine:migrations:sync-metadata-storage
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried but it still not work, i will try again later, because I have a presentation and i don't want to kill everyhing

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem doing

> composer update